# changed method not called on IList dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a custom control in which I have a IList dependency property

```
   public  IList SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList),
          typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnChangeSelectedItems)
          {
              BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
          });

   private static void OnChangeSelectedItems(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var usercontrol = d as MyCustomControl;
        var selected = e.NewValue as IList;

        if (selected != null && selected.Count > 1)
        {

               //do something
                  usercontrol.label1.Content= selected[0];
         }              

    }
```

This Dependency property is binded to an observable collection in Viewmodel,My question is if I add some item in view model observable collection in constructor of Viewmodel OnChangeSelectedItems is getting called,but If i add more items at runtime in  observable collection ,OnChangeSelectedItems is not getting called.What am I missing here.

**EDIT: Working Solution**

```
   private static void OnChangeSelectedItems(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uc = d as UserControl1;

        if (uc != null)
        {
            var oldObservable = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            var newObservable = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (oldObservable != null)
            {
                oldObservable.CollectionChanged -= uc.SelectedItemsContentChanged;
            }
            if (newObservable != null)
            {
                newObservable.CollectionChanged += uc.SelectedItemsContentChanged;


            }
        }
    }

    private void SelectedItemsContentChanged(object d, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: @Clemens While it certainly is a duplicate, I think the linked Q/A is lacking a good title in order to serve as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the change of object (the list itself) with the change of content (the items). `OnChangeSelectedItems` will only be called when the list object is changed.

Inside the change method you can test whether the collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and handle subsequent changes manually.

**Edit**

You want to access the context usercontrol when you perform some operation on items update. This means you need to create a specialized handler instance for the CollectionChanged event. Also, you need to keep track of the handler in order to remove it later when the list is swapped out for some reason. This is done with `CurrentHandlers` in the following code sample.
Code to register for collection changes could look like this:

```
private static Dictionary<INotifyCollectionChanged, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> CurrentHandlers = new Dictionary<INotifyCollectionChanged, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>();

private static void OnChangeSelectedItems(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var usercontrol = d as MyCustomControl;
    var selected = e.NewValue as IList;

    var oldObservable = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    var newObservable = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler;
    if (oldObservable != null && CurrentHandlers.TryGetValue(oldObservable, out handler))
    {
        oldObservable.CollectionChanged -= handler;
        CurrentHandlers.Remove(oldObservable);
    }
    if (newObservable != null)
    {
        handler = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler((sender, e2) => SelectedItemsContentChanged(sender, e2, usercontrol));
        newObservable.CollectionChanged += handler;
        CurrentHandlers.Add(newObservable, handler);
    }

    if (selected != null && selected.Count > 1)
    {
        //do something
    }
}

private static void SelectedItemsContentChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, MyCustomControl usercontrol)
{
    //do something
}
```

Note that this (unlike the previous example) is not really robust. If you bind the same list multiple times, the `CurrentHandlers` storage will not work as intended. So be sure to chose a handler storage mechanism that is safely handling *your* use case of the property.

An idea, that might probably work: `var keyTuple = Tuple.Create(usercontrol, oldObservable);` (or `newObservable`) as key to the `CurrentHandlers` dictionary.

Comment: yes,I also thought so ,but how can I achieve it as List doesn't implement INotifyCollectionChanged .I tried changing IList to observableCollection<object> but it doesn't help.

Comment: @TRS see my edit.

Comment: Thanks ,this seems to work but I was accessing usercontrol coming as part of dependency object parameter in my change handler,but I cant access that in SelectedItemsContentChanged and also "this" keyword is  not allowed because of static.Can you sugesst how to do that also(see code edits in my question)

Comment: @TRS in case you didn't notice: I edited again regarding your additional requirement about accessing the usercontrol.

Comment: Thanks ,I also tried making change handler as member method  of user control class.Do you think this has some flaws(see Edit:Working solution in my question)

Comment: @TRS actually your solution is perfectly fine as long as the handler method logically belongs to the user control. My suggestion is more of a general approach that would work in case where the property / handler isn't part of the user control (like an attached property scenario) but it's not the best for internal handlers.